# Unix script for FOR loop. character to number

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a script in AIX where I am using a FOR loop like shown below:

```
myNumber=<value extracted from a line>
echo $myNumber
tmp=$(($myNumber))
echo $queue

 for i in {1..$tmp}
 do
 //Something
 done
```

I am getting below error message while executing the script. The value for `myNumber` coming as 344 in my case.

`{1..344}`

> Invalid message range parameter '{1..344}..{1..344}'

seems character is not converting into number. HELP guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{1..$tmp}` needs to be expanded after expanding the variable `tmp`.

You can call the shell with the result of expanding `{1..$tmp}`. Assuming `bash`, replace:

```
for i in {1..$tmp}
```

with:

```
for f in $(bash -c "echo {1..$tmp}")
```